# Javascript - Before and after susnset detection

Tags: javascript

This is my first post in stackoverflow. Some amazing minds here, sorry if format is wrong.

With the code below...

**day section** = Will indeed give me a REDSUN 1/2 hour before sunset AND 1/2 hour after sunrise.

**night section** = I will indeed get a REDMOON 1/2 hour after sunset but NOT 1/2 hour before sunrise.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
    if (where == "day") {
        if (twilight == true && Math.abs(time_to_change_wall - nighthour) < 0.5 || Math.abs(time_to_change_wall - dayhour) < 0.5) {
            document.getElementById("redsun").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("redsunray").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("sun").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("moon").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("moonray").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sun").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("sunray").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display = 'block';
        }
    } else {
        if (twilight == true && Math.abs(time_to_change_wall - nighthour) < 0.5 || Math.abs(time_to_change_wall - dayhour) < 0.5) {
            document.getElementById("redmoon").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("redmoonray").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("sun").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("moon").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("moonray").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("sun").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a quetion in your quetion.

Comment: First of all , Welcome to SO ...!!!

Comment: Sorry - I'm wondering why the REDMOON will not display 1/2 hour before sunrise.  Maybe I haven't posted enough code for that question to be answered?

Comment: The relavant HTML and a demo on jsfiddle.net can be a good starting point

Comment: Thanks so much - I just want to make sure I'm posting/asking properly.  I'm big on forum etiquette. Apologies for any "noobie" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there seems to be a logic error in your code. you are attempting to execute the same code segment every time in 2 different cases:

```
if() {
document.getElementById("redmoon").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("redmoonray").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("sun").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("sunray").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display='none';
} else   {
document.getElementById("moon").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("moonray").style.display='block';
document.getElementById("sun").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("sunray").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("sunray1").style.display='none';
}
```

Shouldn't there be different elements showing in each case?

EDIT:

Are you using the same logic regardless whether it's night or day?

Comment: @user568109 - Yes it is. Unless you care to elaborate ? :)

Comment: OK sorry - my goodness.  Having copy/paste issues today.  I think it's all correct now.  So sorry!

Comment: So the idea here is that if it's daytime AND if it's half hour before sunset OR half hour after sunrise = display a red sun.  Otherwise display a normal sun.  If it's night time AND if it's half hour after sunset OR half hour before sunrise = display a red moon.  Otherwise display a normal moon.  Hope that helps maybe?  It all works EXCEPT for the redmoon showing 1/2 hour before sunrise.

Comment: @user2451457 - OK, no problem. Can you show us some more code? I can't be sure whether there is something wrong with your if statement or your markup.

Comment: I was thinking you were talking about inner loop, didn't see the else part. :)

Comment: For sure - I just don't want to post so much that ppl start hating me already :)  I can post the whole file if you like?

Comment: you can provide some of the relevant markup and how you're getting the values in your variables

Comment: Hmmm, from a different, LARGE, js file.  Not sure what to post.  Sorry all.  I might be outta luck I guess :(